# NSMutableArray all values for one key (Kinvey)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, kinvey

I have a NSMutableArray and I add objects (from Kinvey) to it by doing this:

```
KCSQuery* query = [KCSQuery query];

[self.store queryWithQuery:query withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil) {

        [mutableArray removeAllObjects];
        [mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];
    }

} withProgressBlock:nil];
```

Now, I need an array that contains all the objects for just one key, for example, an array of all the ids of the objects inside the mutableArray.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the objects that are in the `mutableArray` array?

Comment: If it's just strings, what do you mean by "key" and "id"?

Comment: I mean the file you download is a string. The id is a string and it belongs to the " _id " key in the Kinvey collection, I just need to have an array that contains only the strings of the " _id " key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `mutableArray` is an array of dictionaries then you can get all the objects for same key from that `mutableArray`.

```
// assuming that you want to retrieve all the "firstName" name from array
NSArray *fnameArray=[mutableArray valueForKey:@"firstName"];
NSLog(@"First Name Array : %@",fnameArray);
```

Please post some data of your `mutableArray` so i can give you proper solution.